How does the electric field and charge distribution get affected by distance and area in a capacitor?

I've posted 3 question until now two of them got cancelled, hope this one doesn't .
My question is simply why does increasing distance affect the charge distribution on parallel capacitors and shouldn't the electric field be constant as it's independent of distance also how does it change with area anyway I'm stumped :(
Edit: another point , how does being connected or disconnected change the behavior of charges and electric field.

(a) By 'parallel capacitors' do you mean capacitors in parallel, or are you referring to the two plates of one parallel plate capacitor? (b) You should explain what you mean by the words you use: for example 'connected capacitor' means (I assume) connected to a constant voltage source, 'distance' means distance between plates and 'Ct.' means constant.

yes , sorry if it's misleading but yeah ct means constant and distance is is the separation between the plates of the parallel plate capacitors


My question is simply why does increasing distance affect the charge distribution on parallel capacitors

You need to make sure you are specifying what is being held constant. IF you see on your table, if the capacitor is disconnected from the battery, then moving the plates of course cannot change the charge on them, because there is nowhere for charges to come from / go to. This is shown on your table as "Ct." which I am guessing means "constant".
If the plates are connected to the battery, then the potential difference between the plates is constant (as it will remain equal to the constant voltage between the terminals of the battery). Assuming infinite parallel plates, the electric field $E$ is proportional to the amount of charge (technically proportional to the charge density). Then by definition of potential, the potential difference $\Delta V$ between the plates is $\Delta V=Ed$, where $d$ is the distance between the plates. Therefore $E$, and hence the charge, to decrease in order for the potential to remain constant as the capacitor is connected to the battery.

and shouldn't the electric field be constant as it's independent of distance

This was already covered above, but you need to be very careful about what is being held constant and what is changing. $E$ is directly proportional to the charge on the plates, and so anything that changes that charge will change the field. A change in distance between the plates can change the amount of charge, and hence the field can change (as shown above)

also how does it change with area

Hopefully from here you can figure out the arguments. Although you need to be careful because the electric field is proportional to $q/A$

Really appreciated but i just want to know the underlying interaction that makes the voltage constant that is if E is proportional to q/A and a is held constant how what interaction does changing distance  make to reduce surface charge density and thus reduces the field strength

I assume that, in your comment on Biophysicist's excellent answer, you're referring to the case when the capacitor is connected to a battery (assumed to keep the pd, $\Delta V$, across the capacitor constant). As $d$ is increased the field strength, magnitude $E$, decreases because $E=\tfrac {\Delta V}d$. While $d$ is being increased, the capacitor will partly discharge through the battery, that is negative charge will flow from the negative plate, through the battery to the positive plate, so reducing the magnitude, $Q$, of charge on each plate, in accordance with $E=\tfrac Q{\epsilon_0 A}$.


Yes not the most appealing answer but it works , If the capacitor was connected to a battery you hold the voltage constant and if it wasn't you hold the charge constant and from there you can determine the change in other variables.
eg: if the distance increases capacitance decreases (second equation)  and because voltage is held constant q must be increased because capacitance increased ( equation one)

Please don't post pictures of text and equations
